# What's the meaning of default: classes in this makefile?

Tags: java, linux, unix, makefile, gnu-make

The comment for this is "the default make target entry".
Could anyone explain more on this line?
And why we use "default" rather than "all" here? Can I change the name to whatever I want?
Thanks!

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
        Foo.java \
        Blah.java \
        Library.java \
        Main.java 

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
        $(RM) *.class
```

Comment: We _very much_ prefer that you include your code in the question, instead of linking to it (and _especially_ instead of linking to a .png file, which means that we can't copy-and-paste to try things ourselves).  Your file is only 18 lines which is well below our threshold for when we start thinking someone has posted too much code.

Comment: @ajb Already update. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the word "default" is "implicit", or "that if none is given".  Here in makefiles, it would be if you call

```
>make
```

without a goal explicitly stated, then the first target in your makefile (other than ones starting with `.`) is updated.  So it makes sense for the first such target to be called "default".  Yes you can change it to something else if you want to confuse everybody.

However, by convention from the Make manual, the name of the first target is already supposed to be `all`.  So `all` is better than `default` which is better than anything else.

Also, "default make target entry" is a poor comment.  The proper terminology is "make goal", and to comment the target which one has named `default` with "default" is a waste of characters :)